# Integration of Taylor series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am having trouble with the following question:

Integrate the Taylor series:

$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{d^if(x)|_{x_0}}{dx}(x-x_0)^i$

I know that we can represent this function as the sum of integrals under some condition?

$f(x)=\int \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{d^if(x)|_{x_0}}{dx}(x-x_0)^i \underset{?}{=} \sum \int d^i...$

But I don't understand how to finish this calculation.

Can any one give me a hand with this?

Comment: Nitpick: you should write $\left.\frac{d^if(x)}{dx^i}\right|_{x_0}$ instead of $\frac{d^if(x)|_{x_0}}{dx^i}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you omitted $i!$ from the denominator of the generic term.

You've also omitted the constant term (the term where $i=0$).

In the generic term $\frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^i}{i!}$, the factor  $\frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}$ is a constant, so it comes out of the integral as a multiplier; the only part you need to worry about integrating is $(x-x_0)^i$.

And you will have an arbitrary additive constant as well, unless this is a definite integral.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand you right and if I have define integral I can now represent it like: $f(x)=\int \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^i}{i!}=\frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}\int \sum_{i=1}^\infty (x-x_0)^i$ Is it immediately follows from it that $ \frac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}\int \sum_{i=1}^\infty (x-x_0)^i\underset{?}{=} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int (x-x_0)^i$

Comment: Not quite. You've still omitted the constant term, and you can't bring the dummy index outside of the sum. You should have $$\int_a^b\left( \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \tfrac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}(x-x_0)^i\right)\; dx = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\tfrac{f^{(i)}(x_0)}{i!}\int_a^b (x-x_0)^i\; dx\right)$$ and note that the constant term (where $i=0$) must be handled specially since when $i=0$ the term is really $f(x_0)\int_a^b dx$.